# How to properly fix React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, usecallback, react-usecallback

I updated my Eslint rules using `airbnb` in my React typescript project.

I get those errors now:

> React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'setCookie'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency
> array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I have this in the extend property inside eslintrc.js:

```
extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
],
```

How to properly fix those errors? When is it a good practice to add or not to add the dependencie prop(s)?

Answer (score 0):

It's very bad experience if you remove it at all, rather than throwing error, i would like to throw a warning instead by adding this to your eslintrc rules:

```
"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
```

Comment: But those errors are vallid right? It's good to fix them. So how to fix them instead of 'warn'?

Comment: sure man, you shouldn't ignore it, so you have to add it to the dependencies array